# ASP Classic - "Content-aware" links within an included document

Tags: asp-classic, ssis

I'm currently re-designing a site utilizing what appears to be relatively limited ASP scripting.  The site contains many articles.  I've gone ahead and built a "toolbar" that will be added as an #include in each article, and this toolbar contains a list of "Share this page" links pointing to various social networking sites.

For testing purposes, I've gone ahead and used absolute URLs, but I would now like to utilize this toolbar on other articles.  My question is this: how do I make these "Share this page" links refer only to the page in which the toolbar was included?  For example, what I'm currently using is this **absolute link**:

a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=Currently%20reading:%20 **http://www.drlam.com/dev/afc/article/NEW_adrenal_fatigue.asp**" target="_blank"

What I'm thinking needs to be done is something more dynamic, like **this**:

a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=Currently%20reading:%20 **<%current_page%>**" target="_blank"

Pardon my ignorance with respect to ASP terminology & structure. I'm learning, here :)

Comment: is current_page the page you are currently on?

Comment: Yes, sir.  I will try your solution below to start!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the current page in an include file from the Request.ServerVariables but may also need to check for any querystring or form values using the Request Object

```
Dim current_page
current_page = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & Request.ServerVariables("URL")
```

Comment: Hello Paul,  Yes <%current_page%> would be the article with the #included toolbar.  Not being too familiar with asp or scripting in general, I suppose I would have to first define <%current_page%>, yes?  edit: Oh sorry, I'm not too familiar with SO.  I'll try this solution now!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for the help, Paul McCowat! While it's not verbatim, the following seems to be doing the trick.  If there's something I'm missing that making this run less efficiently, I'm all ears on how to implement a better solution!

```
<%
current_page ="http://www." & Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & Request.ServerVariables("URL")
Referpage = Request.ServerVariables("http_referer")
%>
```